# Java Applet Checkbox bug

Tags: java, applet, checkbox

I am having problems with my java checkbox applet. I got it mostly working but I ended up with a minor bug. When I select soup the salad should be grayed out (and it is), but if I already have selected an item from salad and then click soup, salad becomes grayed out and the item (inside salad) is still selected.

```
public class Applet_11 extends Applet implements ItemListener
{
Panel
    dinnerPanel,
    soupPanel,
    saladPanel;

Checkbox
    standard, deluxe,
    soup, salad, 
    cream, broth, gumbo,
    tossed, caesar,
    croutons,lite;

//Used to setup all of the boxes and add them to the Applet
public void init()
{
    CheckboxGroup dinnerType = new CheckboxGroup();
    standard = new Checkbox("standard", dinnerType, false);
    standard.addItemListener(this);
    deluxe = new Checkbox("deluxe", dinnerType, true);
    deluxe.addItemListener(this);

    CheckboxGroup soupOrSalad = new CheckboxGroup();
    soup = new Checkbox("Soup", soupOrSalad, false);
    soup.addItemListener(this);
    salad = new Checkbox("Salad", soupOrSalad, false);
    salad.addItemListener(this);

    CheckboxGroup soups = new CheckboxGroup();
    cream = new Checkbox("cream", soups, false);
    cream.addItemListener(this);
    broth = new Checkbox("broth", soups, false);
    broth.addItemListener(this);
    gumbo = new Checkbox("gumbo", soups, false);
    gumbo.addItemListener(this);

    CheckboxGroup salads = new CheckboxGroup();
    tossed = new Checkbox("tossed", salads, false);
    tossed.addItemListener(this);
    caesar = new Checkbox("ceasar", salads, false);
    caesar.addItemListener(this);
    croutons = new Checkbox("croutons", salads, false);
    croutons.addItemListener(this);
    lite = new Checkbox("lite", salads, false);
    lite.addItemListener(this);

    //adding the componets to the Applet
    setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

    dinnerPanel = new Panel();
    add(dinnerPanel);
    dinnerPanel.add(standard);
    dinnerPanel.add(deluxe);

    soupPanel = new Panel();
    add(soupPanel);
    soupPanel.add(soup);
    soupPanel.add(cream);
    soupPanel.add(broth);
    soupPanel.add(gumbo);

    saladPanel = new Panel();
    add(saladPanel);
    saladPanel.add(salad);
    saladPanel.add(tossed);
    saladPanel.add(caesar);
    saladPanel.add(croutons);
    saladPanel.add(lite);
}

//ItemEvents and calls other functions
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
{
    if (e.getSource() == standard || e.getSource() == deluxe) { 
        handleDinnerType((Checkbox)e.getSource());
    } else if (e.getSource() == soup || e.getSource() == salad) { 
        handleSoupSaladChoice((Checkbox)e.getSource());
    }    
}    

//helper function for dinner type
void handleDinnerType(Checkbox selectedType) 
{
    boolean enabled = false;

    if (selectedType == standard) {
        enabled = false;    
    } else if (selectedType == deluxe) {
        enabled = true;
    }

    cream.setEnabled(enabled);
    broth.setEnabled(enabled);
    gumbo.setEnabled(enabled);
    tossed.setEnabled(enabled);
    caesar.setEnabled(enabled);
    croutons.setEnabled(enabled);
    lite.setEnabled(enabled);

}

//helper function for salad and soup type
void handleSoupSaladChoice(Checkbox selectedCourse) 
{
    boolean soupEnabled, saladEnabled;

    if (selectedCourse == soup) {
        soupEnabled = true;
        saladEnabled = false;
    } else {
        soupEnabled = false;
        saladEnabled = true;
    }

    cream.setEnabled(soupEnabled);
    broth.setEnabled(soupEnabled);
    gumbo.setEnabled(soupEnabled);

    tossed.setEnabled(saladEnabled);
    caesar.setEnabled(saladEnabled);
    croutons.setEnabled(saladEnabled);
    lite.setEnabled(saladEnabled);
}
}
```

Comment: before I post anything else I would recommend storing everything in an array/arraylist, will probably make your code 1/4 of what is is currently

Comment: this is for a class assignment, and we havent got up to arrays yet, and i dont want to jump ahead. But I understand it will be easier and shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're asking about is half-check-box and half-radio-button, and there's two ways to tackle it:

1. Add an extra Checkbox in the Checkboxgroup, which basically says 'none of the other options'.  And set the state of that Checkbox in your listener. Because once you select an option in a Checkbox group you cannot clear it I believe.
2. Remove the Checkboxgroup and have your listener manage the exclusion of other checkboxes instead of relying on the Checkboxgroup.  Sample code for this is

-

```
public class Applet_15934232 extends Applet implements ItemListener {
    Panel
            dinnerPanel,
            soupPanel,
            saladPanel;

    Checkbox
            standard, deluxe,
            soup, salad,
            cream, broth, gumbo,
            tossed, caesar,
            croutons, lite;

    //Used to setup all of the boxes and add them to the Applet
    public void init() {
        CheckboxGroup dinnerType = new CheckboxGroup();
        standard = new Checkbox("standard", dinnerType, false);
        standard.addItemListener(this);
        deluxe = new Checkbox("deluxe", dinnerType, true);
        deluxe.addItemListener(this);

        CheckboxGroup soupOrSalad = new CheckboxGroup();
        soup = new Checkbox("Soup", soupOrSalad, false);
        soup.addItemListener(this);
        salad = new Checkbox("Salad", soupOrSalad, false);
        salad.addItemListener(this);

        cream = new Checkbox("cream", false);
        cream.addItemListener(this);
        broth = new Checkbox("broth", false);
        broth.addItemListener(this);
        gumbo = new Checkbox("gumbo", false);
        gumbo.addItemListener(this);

        tossed = new Checkbox("tossed", false);
        tossed.addItemListener(this);
        caesar = new Checkbox("ceasar", false);
        caesar.addItemListener(this);
        croutons = new Checkbox("croutons", false);
        croutons.addItemListener(this);
        lite = new Checkbox("lite", false);
        lite.addItemListener(this);


        //adding the componets to the Applet
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        dinnerPanel = new Panel();
        add(dinnerPanel);
        dinnerPanel.add(standard);
        dinnerPanel.add(deluxe);

        soupPanel = new Panel();
        add(soupPanel);
        soupPanel.add(soup);
        soupPanel.add(cream);
        soupPanel.add(broth);
        soupPanel.add(gumbo);

        saladPanel = new Panel();
        add(saladPanel);
        saladPanel.add(salad);
        saladPanel.add(tossed);
        saladPanel.add(caesar);
        saladPanel.add(croutons);
        saladPanel.add(lite);
    }

    //ItemEvents and calls other functions
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == standard || e.getSource() == deluxe) {
            handleDinnerType((Checkbox) e.getSource());
        } else if (e.getSource() == soup || e.getSource() == salad) {
            handleSoupSaladChoice((Checkbox) e.getSource());
        } else {
            handleButtonSelection((Checkbox) e.getSource());
        }
    }

    private void handleButtonSelection(Checkbox source) {
        cream.setState(source == cream);
        broth.setState(source == broth);
        gumbo.setState(source == gumbo);
        tossed.setState(source == tossed);
        caesar.setState(source == caesar);
        croutons.setState(source == croutons);
        lite.setState(source == lite);
    }

    //helper function for dinner type
    void handleDinnerType(Checkbox selectedType) {
        boolean enabled = false;

        if (selectedType == standard) {
            enabled = false;
        } else if (selectedType == deluxe) {
            enabled = true;
        }

        cream.setEnabled(enabled);
        broth.setEnabled(enabled);
        gumbo.setEnabled(enabled);
        tossed.setEnabled(enabled);
        caesar.setEnabled(enabled);
        croutons.setEnabled(enabled);
        lite.setEnabled(enabled);

    }

    //helper function for salad and soup type
    void handleSoupSaladChoice(Checkbox selectedCourse) {
        boolean soupEnabled = (selectedCourse == soup);
        boolean saladEnabled = (selectedCourse == salad);

        if (soupEnabled) {
            tossed.setState(false);
            caesar.setState(false);
            croutons.setState(false);
            lite.setState(false);
        }
        if (saladEnabled) {
            cream.setState(false);
            broth.setState(false);
            gumbo.setState(false);
        }


        cream.setEnabled(soupEnabled);
        broth.setEnabled(soupEnabled);
        gumbo.setEnabled(soupEnabled);

        tossed.setEnabled(saladEnabled);
        caesar.setEnabled(saladEnabled);
        croutons.setEnabled(saladEnabled);
        lite.setEnabled(saladEnabled);
    }
}
```